# Keyboard no longer works Intermittently after suspend 18.04 Dell Inspiron 13

Tags: keyboard, suspend, dell, inspiron

Intermittently, my Dell Inspiron 13 with Ubuntu 18.04 doesn't let my keyboard work after suspend. There is no pattern that I can discern. Touchpad still works. Touchscreen still works, allowing me to still use the touch-keyboard to login - from there, I have to close all programs, restart the system, in order to get the keyboard working again.

I have tried switching to LightDm - it doesn't work.
I have tried working with GRUB_CMDLINE_LINUX or to GRUB_CMDLINE_LINUX_DEFAULT - it doesn't work.
I have tried various solutions to do with NVIDIA drivers - they don't work.

I am now at the point where, if I can not find a resolution to this problem, I will switch to a completely different Linux OS, despite having worked with various versions of Ubuntu over a decade.

I simply cannot do my job with an OS that makes the simple process of suspend/restore ineffective.

Solutions very, very welcome.

Comment: Have you tried the 18.04 HWE? (`sudo apt install --install-recommends linux-generic-hwe-18.04 xserver-xorg-hwe-18.04`.) It contains various improvements for Dell XPS 13 suspend issues but I cannot say for Inspiron as I don't have one.

Comment: I got: 
"Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree       
Reading state information... Done
linux-generic-hwe-18.04 is already the newest version (5.0.0.27.84).
xserver-xorg-hwe-18.04 is already the newest version (1:7.7+19ubuntu8~18.04.2).
0 to upgrade, 0 to newly install, 0 to remove and 0 not to upgrade."